# argument of type "WCHAR **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"

Tags: c++, networking, adapter

I am trying to make a network utilization program that shows the current bps of an adapter. I got it all working inside main but now I want to move it out into a function I can call. I apologise in advance, I am a n00b and this is probably a basic question but when I move all the code out into a function and compile I get the following error message:

argument of type "WCHAR **" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"

(My code is here: https://pastebin.com/h7S9e1Zk It is a heavily modified version of an example I found).

```cpp
long long test(WCHAR** args) {
    std::cout << "running:" << args << ":End" << "\n";

    // Declare and initialize variables

    ULONG retVal1 = 0;
    ULONG retVal2 = 0;
    ULONG ifIndex1;
    ULONG ifIndex2;

    MIB_IF_ROW2 ifRow1;
    MIB_IF_ROW2 ifRow2;

    // Make sure the ifRow is zeroed out
    SecureZeroMemory((PVOID)&ifRow1, sizeof(MIB_IF_ROW2));

    // Zero out the MIB_IF_ROW2 struct

    ifIndex1 = _wtoi(args);

    ifRow1.InterfaceIndex = ifIndex1;

    retVal1 = GetIfEntry2(&ifRow1);

    long long oct1 = PrintIfEntry2(&ifRow1);


    Sleep(1000);

    // Make sure the ifRow is zeroed out
    SecureZeroMemory((PVOID)&ifRow2, sizeof(MIB_IF_ROW2));

    ifIndex2 = _wtoi(args);

    ifRow2.InterfaceIndex = ifIndex2;

    retVal2 = GetIfEntry2(&ifRow2);

    long long oct2 = PrintIfEntry2(&ifRow2);

    long long rise = (oct2 - oct1) * 8;

    //rise = rise / 1000 / 1000;

    return rise;
}
```

It is specifically referencing this bit of code:

ifIndex1 = _wtoi(args);

I am guessing I have gotten my casts mixed up but for the life of me I cannot see where I have gone wrong.

Any advice?

Comment: Why did you make the function's parameter a `WCHAR**` and not `WCHAR*`? You're doing `_wtoi(args)` twice as if you expect a different result the second time - did you intend to pass only part of the `argv` array to this function (your cast there is completely wrong)?

Comment: All for the want of a bloody *. Thank you so much. I am at the stage of just getting the thing working, then I am going to go through and clean it up/streamline it. Thanks again :)